# Referencing a legislation with Biblatex and Apa Style

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am writing a thesis in Law, and for that reason, I need to make references to many acts of legislation, both from the US and the EU. Following my university's templates, I also need to insert the references in the footnotes and at the end of the document.

Trying to achieve the best result for that, I'm currently using Biblatex with the APA style. However, when it comes to the legislation I need to refer to, I cannot make it show all the fields required by the APA 7th style.

I need the references to show all information as in these examples:
(1) [APA 7th Referencing: Legislation & Cases](https://libraryguides.vu.edu.au/apa-referencing/7LegislationCases)
(2) [Citing a Bill in 7th Edition APA](https://www.alverno.edu/media/alvernocollege/library/pdfs/apa7bill.pdf).

My .bib file contains this information:

```
    @legislation{Eshoo_2021,
    keywords={norm},
    chapter={117th Congress (2021-2022)},
    title={Online Privacy Act of 2021}, 
    url={https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/6027?s=7&r=828},
    number={H.R.6027}, 
    author={Eshoo, Anna G.},
    year={2021},
    month={11},
}
```

But the final appearance is this:

> Online Privacy Act of 2021, 2021, https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/6027?s=7&r=828

It shows the title, the year, and the URL, but I need it to show also the bill number and the number of the Congress.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little bit messy currently as there are no good rules for mapping such information to obvious fields. Currently the style uses `LOCATION` for such material - see the examples from the package test document which typsets every example in the APA 7th edition manual, including the legal references:

https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/master/bibtex/bib/biblatex-apa-test-references.bib#L2563

Comment: Thank you @PLK!

I had previously seen those examples, but I hadn't really processed the information.

In the lack of a better solution, changing the information from `CHAPTER` and `NUMBER` into `LOCATION` worked for now.

It's going to be a pain in the a** to edit every single entry from my reference manager when creating the .bib file, but at least it works.

Thank you!!